# Vértice mais próximo de outro - Postgis

Tags: sql

Existe a possibilidade de retornar o vértice mais próximo de outro? Sendo que uma das geometrias observadas é uma linestring. Como na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero retornar o único vértice da linestring (que é representado pelos pontos em preto) que é mais próximo do ponto em vermelho (que não pertence a linestring, mas está sobre ela).
Existe alguma função no postgis para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função: [ST_ClosestPoint()](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html)

```
SELECT 
    ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(linha_qualquer, ponto_escolhido)) AS vertice_mais_proximo
FROM (
    SELECT
            l.geom AS linha_qualquer,
            p.geom AS ponto_escolhido
    FROM 
            linhas l, pontos p
    WHERE 
            p.gid = 1
) AS foo;
```